# Why does +0.0 > -0.0 not hold for IEEE754 floats?

Tags: floating-accuracy, ieee-754

IEEE754 floating point numbers have the concept of a [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), i.e. there are two different bit patterns for `-0.0` and `+0.0`, which can be understood as one-sided limits: ±0 := lim<sub>*δ*→0</sub> ±*δ*.   The standard provides these numbers for consistency with the (signed) infinities `+Inf` and `-Inf` (`1./±0.` gives `±Inf`), and there is some evidence that it helps reduce roundoff errors.

It is clear from the limit that while they are different entities, they *compare* to the same value, i.e, `+0.0 == -0.0` holds.  However, from the limit I would also think that the following thing should hold: `+0.0 > -0.0`, since it holds for any small *δ*.  This however is *not true*.  Since this property would occasionally be useful (think about distinguishing the two zeros, for example),  is there any compelling reason why the standards committee chose not to do that?

Comment: A simple explanation would be that 2 numbers can not be equal at the same time as one being greater than the other.

Comment: Well, sure, that certainly makes sense. However, it begs the question: if they are the same, why do they behave differently in operations? Put another way: why do we choose to follow the "mathematical rules" of the limit in some cases, but not in others?

Comment: Start reading with Kahan's article at https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF and follow links that you find there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffinelyExtendedRealNumbers.html)'s article on the number system underlying floating-point arithmetic cites [David Goldberg's famous paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#924), which says,

> Although distinguishing between +0 and -0 has advantages, it can occasionally be confusing. For example, signed zero destroys the relation x = y ⇔ 1/x = 1/y, which is false when x = +0 and y = -0. However, the IEEE committee decided that the advantages of utilizing the sign of zero outweighed the disadvantages.

The committee has a [website](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754) which can be [searched](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site:http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754+%22signed+zero%22) for such discussion, and it looks like signed zeroes are the source of perpetual controversy.

I can't find anything there about your particular question. But just as a speculation, it's possible that they wanted to simplify the hardware, that comparison only produces a result from the set {less, greater, equal, unordered}. Allowing both –0 < +0 and –0 = +0 would complicate (and potentially slow) some circuitry. It might have been deemed uneconomical.